# Tabbed Slider Panel combination is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs, slider

I am trying to program a slider that is split into tabs in order to showcase a large variety of products by category, but I am having difficulty getting this to work correctly.

I have used both the Tabs and Slider individually without any issues, but when they are used together it is not functioning correctly, which I think is to do with the Javascript I used (which was pulled from another source and adapted with my limited knowledge).

The problem is every slider except the one in the first will not slide or display properly, which I think is because the names of the slider elements that Javascript responds to is used more than once because of the tabs.

Here is a codepen of what I have done so far:

https://codepen.io/UXLou/pen/PowJMgX

Initially I tried to put the entire slider in each tab, but this was even less functional.

Please can somebody have a look at this?  Bear in mind I know pretty much no Javascript so please keep your answers simple.

Here is the Javascript in case it doesn't work properly in the link:

```js
// code for bottom page tabs

function openRegion(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();


// Carousel Coding

  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
//set here the speed to change the slides in the carousel or pause them
        $('#myCarousel').carousel({
                pause: true,
                interval: 0
        });
     
//Loads the html to each slider. Write in the "div id="slide-content-x" what you want to show in each slide
        $('carousel-caption').html($('#slide-content-0').html());
 
//Handles the carousel thumbnails
       $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
            var id = this.id.substr(this.id.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);
            console.log('Change: ',id);
            var idNum = parseInt(id);
            $('#myCarousel').carousel(idNum);
            
        });
 
// When the carousel slides, auto update the text
        $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
                var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
     
 //update active thumbnail!!
                $('.SA-slider-thumb').removeClass('active');
                $('#carousel-selector-'+id).addClass('active');
                
                $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-'+id).html());

        });
});

$('.SA-slider-thumb').click(function(){
  $('.SA-slider-thumb').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
/* Tab Styling */
.hot-chocolate-heaven .static-content-front-page-flex-container .four-image-row, .static-content-front-page-flex-container .four-image-row .tab {width: 100%;}
.hot-chocolate-heaven .static-content-front-page-flex-container .four-image-row .tab {border-bottom: 1px solid #435764; margin-bottom: 24px;}
.hot-chocolate-heaven .static-content-front-page-flex-container .four-image-row .tab button {font-size: 16px; background: transparent; border: none; color: #435764; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: AvenirLTStd-Black; padding: 40px 0px 0px 0px !important; width: 16.225%; opacity: 0.4; vertical-align: bottom;}
.hot-chocolate-heaven .static-content-front-page-flex-container .four-image-row .tab button.active {border-bottom: 4px solid #435764; margin-bottom: -3px; opacity: 1;}
.hot-chocolate-heaven .static-content-front-page-flex-container .four-image-row .tab button:focus {outline:0;}
.hot-chocolate-heaven .static-content-front-page-flex-container .four-image-row .packitem {width: 33.33%;}
.hot-chocolate-heaven .static-content-front-page-flex-container .four-image-row .button-outline-2 {font-size: 16px; text-transform: initial; display: inline-block; margin: 12px 0;}
.hot-chocolate-heaven .static-content.hero-slider .carousel-text-section .carousel-text-content {display: table; height: 100%;}
.hot-chocolate-heaven .static-content-plp-full-width-image {display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; position: relative;}
.hot-chocolate-heaven .static-content.hero-slider .carousel-text-section {height: 100%; top: 0px;}
.hot-chocolate-heaven .static-content.hero-slider .carousel-text-content .slide-title-tea {margin-top: 0px;}
.hot-chocolate-heaven .static-content.hero-slider .carousel-text-section .container {max-width: 1440px; margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; display: table; height: 100%;}
.hot-chocolate-heaven .static-content-front-page-flex-container {-webkit-box-orient: horizontal !important; flex-direction: row !important; -ms-flex-direction: row !important; max-width: 1440px;}
.hot-chocolate-heaven .static-content-front-page-flex-container .avenir-head, .hero-slider .avenir-head {text-transform: uppercase; font-family: AvenirLTStd-Medium; width: 100%; color: #435764;}
.hot-chocolate-heaven .static-content-front-page-flex-container .didot, .hero-slider .didot {font-family: DidotLTPro-Roman; font-style: italic; text-transform: initial;}
.hot-chocolate-flavours .SA-slider-thumbs {position: relative; width: 70%; float: right;}

/* Carousel Styling */
#carousel-bounding-box {padding-left: 0px;}
.hot-chocolate-flavours .carousel-caption {left: 0 !important; text-shadow: none !important; width: 100%; top: 0% !important; padding: 24px !important; height: 100%; position: relative; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; width: 30%;}
.hot-chocolate-flavours .carousel-caption h2 {text-transform: initial; font-family: AvenirLTStd-Medium; color: #fff; font-size: 30px; max-width: 540px; margin: 0 auto; line-height: 1.3em; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;}
.hot-chocolate-flavours .container {width: 100%;}
.hot-chocolate-flavours h1 {font-size: 42px;}
.hot-chocolate-flavours h3 {font-family: DidotLTPro-Roman; font-size: 48px;}
.hot-chocolate-flavours p {font-size: 16px;}
.hot-chocolate-flavours .special {text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 28px !important; font-family: AvenirLTStd-Medium !important; background: rgb(255,255,255); background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(216,164,80,1) 36%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 66%, rgba(216,164,80,1) 100%); background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(216,164,80,1) 36%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 66%,rgba(216,164,80,1) 100%); background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(216,164,80,1) 36%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 66%,rgba(216,164,80,1) 100%); filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#d8a450',GradientType=1 ); -webkit-background-clip: text; -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;}

.hot-chocolate-flavours #SA-slider-thumbs .active{opacity: 1; background-color: #e3e3e3 !important; border: 10px solid #e3e3e3 !important; transition: all 0.4s ease;}
.hot-chocolate-flavours .SA-slider-thumb {opacity: 0.3; border: none; padding: 0px; margin: 10px 0;}
.hot-chocolate-flavours .SA-slider-thumb:hover {opacity: 0.5; background-color: transparent !important;}
.hot-chocolate-flavours .SA-slider-thumb img {margin-bottom: 8px;}
.hot-chocolate-flavours .carousel-inner>.item>a>img, .carousel-inner>.item>img, .hot-chocolate-flavours .carousel-inner>.item>a>img, .carousel-inner>.item>picture>img {height: 494px !important; overflow: hidden; object-fit: cover; width: 100%;}
.hide-bullets li {list-style-type: none;}

.hot-chocolate-flavours .hero-slider .carousel {display: table; position: relative; width: 100%; height: 300px;}
.hot-chocolate-flavours .hero-slider .carousel-inner {display: table-cell; width: 30%; height: 100%; position: absolute;}
.hot-chocolate-flavours .hero-slider #SA-slider-thumbs {display: table-cell; width: 70%; max-height: 500px; overflow: scroll;}
.hot-chocolate-flavours .preview .carousel-caption h2 {max-width: 520px;}
.hot-chocolate-flavours .vip .carousel-caption h2 {max-width: 475px;}
.carousel-inner>.item {height: 100%;}
.carousel-inner>.item .item-inner {height: 100%; display: table;}

.hot-chocolate-flavours .hero-slider #SA-slider-thumbs .hide-bullets, .hot-chocolate-flavours .hero-slider #SA-slider-thumbs .hide-bullets li {list-style: none; padding: 0px;}
.hot-chocolate-flavours .hero-slider #SA-slider-thumbs .hide-bullets li a {padding: 12px; border: none !important; color: #3f5262; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: AvenirLTStd-Medium; line-height: 1.2em; min-height: 185px; background-color: transparent; box-shadow: none;}
.hot-chocolate-flavours .static-content.hero-slider {background-color: #f5f5f5; height: 100%; margin-bottom: 20px;}
.hot-choc-heaven .hot-choc-info {display: table; height: 100%; width: 100%;}
.hot-choc-heaven .carousel-caption .hot-choc-info-inner {padding: 24px !important; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; height: 100%; text-transform: initial; font-family: AvenirLTStd-Medium; color: #fff; font-size: 30px; max-width: 540px; margin: 0 auto; line-height: 1.3em; vertical-align: middle;}
```

```html
<div class="hot-chocolate-heaven">
<!-- Hot chcolate Heaven tabs -->
     <div class="static-content-front-page-flex-container">
          <div class="static-content four-image-row maxwidth-2 dark-text">
               <div class="tab">
                    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openRegion(event, 'pack1')" id="defaultOpen">SPECIAL EDITION</button>
                    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openRegion(event, 'pack2')">CLASSIC</button>
                    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openRegion(event, 'pack3')">FRUITY</button>
               </div>

               <div class="static-content-front-page-flex-container four-item">

                    <div class="hot-chocolate-flavours">
<div class="static-content hero-slider">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="main_area">
    <!-- Slider -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12" id="slider">
        <!-- Top part of the slider -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12" id="carousel-bounding-box">
            <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">

<!-- First Tab -->
          <div id="pack1" class="tabcontent">
              <!-- Carousel items -->
              <div class="carousel-inner">

                <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0">
                     <div class="item-inner">
                          <div class="carousel-caption" style="background-color: rgb(143, 63, 87);">
                               <div class="hot-choc-info">
                                    <div class="hot-choc-info-inner">
                                    <h1>Our Hot chocolates</h1><p>Find your flavour!</p>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                          </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="item preview" data-slide-number="1">
                     <div class="item-inner">
                          <div class="carousel-caption" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
                               <div class="hot-choc-info">
                                    <div class="hot-choc-info-inner">
                                    <h3 class="special">SPECIAL EDITION</h3><h3>Flavour</h3><p>Dummy Text</p>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                          </div>
                     </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item" data-slide-number="2">
                     <div class="item-inner">
                          <div class="carousel-caption" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
                               <div class="hot-choc-info">
                                    <div class="hot-choc-info-inner">
                                    <h3 class="special">SPECIAL EDITION</h3><h3>Flavour</h3><p>Dummy Text</p>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                          </div>
                     </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item" data-slide-number="3">
                     <div class="item-inner">
                          <div class="carousel-caption" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
                               <div class="hot-choc-info">
                                    <div class="hot-choc-info-inner">
                                    <h3 class="special">SPECIAL EDITION</h3><h3>Flavour</h3><p>Dummy Text</p>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                          </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="item" data-slide-number="4">
                     <div class="item-inner">
                          <div class="carousel-caption" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
                               <div class="hot-choc-info">
                                    <div class="hot-choc-info-inner">
                                    <h3>Flavour</h3><p>Dummy Text</p>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                          </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="item vip" data-slide-number="5">
                     <div class="item-inner">
                          <div class="carousel-caption" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
                               <div class="hot-choc-info">
                                    <div class="hot-choc-info-inner">
                                    <h3>Flavour</h3><p>Dummy Text</p>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                          </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="item" data-slide-number="6">
                     <div class="item-inner">
                          <div class="carousel-caption" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
                               <div class="hot-choc-info">
                                    <div class="hot-choc-info-inner">
                                    <h3>Flavour</h3><p>Dummy Text</p>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                          </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="item" data-slide-number="7">
                     <div class="item-inner">
                          <div class="carousel-caption" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
                               <div class="hot-choc-info">
                                    <div class="hot-choc-info-inner">
                                    <h3>Flavour</h3><p>Dummy Text</p>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                          </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="item" data-slide-number="8">
                     <div class="item-inner">
                          <div class="carousel-caption" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
                               <div class="hot-choc-info">
                                    <div class="hot-choc-info-inner">
                                    <h3>Flavour</h3><p>Dummy Text</p>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                          </div>
                     </div>
                </div>


              </div>


                  <div class="row SA-slider-thumbs" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Bottom switcher of slider -->
      <ul class="hide-bullets">
        <li class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4" style="display: none;">
          <a data-target="SA-slider-thumbs" class="thumbnail active SA-slider-thumb" id="carousel-selector-0"><img src="images/clps/hot-chocolate/marzipan-hot-chocolate.jpg?$staticlink$">Hot chocolate Flavours/a>
        </li>

        <li class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
          <a data-target="SA-slider-thumbs" class="thumbnail SA-slider-thumb" id="carousel-selector-1"><img src="https://i1.wp.com/www.charitycomms.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/placeholder-image-square.jpg?ssl=1">Flavour</a>
        </li>

        <li class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
          <a data-target="SA-slider-thumbs" class="thumbnail SA-slider-thumb" id="carousel-selector-2"><img src="https://i1.wp.com/www.charitycomms.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/placeholder-image-square.jpg?ssl=1">Flavour</a>
        </li>

        <li class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
          <a data-target="SA-slider-thumbs" class="thumbnail SA-slider-thumb" id="carousel-selector-3"><img src="https://i1.wp.com/www.charitycomms.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/placeholder-image-square.jpg?ssl=1">Flavour</a>
        </li>

        <li class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
          <a data-target="SA-slider-thumbs" class="thumbnail SA-slider-thumb" id="carousel-selector-4"><img src="https://i1.wp.com/www.charitycomms.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/placeholder-image-square.jpg?ssl=1">Flavour</a>
        </li>
        
        <li class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 row-2">
          <a data-target="SA-slider-thumbs" class="thumbnail SA-slider-thumb" id="carousel-selector-5"><img src="https://i1.wp.com/www.charitycomms.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/placeholder-image-square.jpg?ssl=1">Flavour</a>
        </li>

        <li class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 row-2">
          <a data-target="SA-slider-thumbs" class="thumbnail SA-slider-thumb" id="carousel-selector-6"><img src="https://i1.wp.com/www.charitycomms.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/placeholder-image-square.jpg?ssl=1">Flavour</a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 row-2">
          <a data-target="SA-slider-thumbs" class="thumbnail SA-slider-thumb" id="carousel-selector-7"><img src="https://i1.wp.com/www.charitycomms.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/placeholder-image-square.jpg?ssl=1">Flavour</a>
        </li>

        <li class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 row-2">
          <a data-target="SA-slider-thumbs" class="thumbnail SA-slider-thumb" id="carousel-selector-8"><img src="https://i1.wp.com/www.charitycomms.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/placeholder-image-square.jpg?ssl=1">Flavour</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
            
              

            </div>
    <!--/Slider-->



<!-- Second Tab -->
          <div id="pack2" class="tabcontent">
              <!-- Carousel items -->
              <div class="carousel-inner">

                <div class="active item" data-slide-number="9">
                     <div class="item-inner">
                          <div class="carousel-caption" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
                               <div class="hot-choc-info">
                                    <div class="hot-choc-info-inner">
                                    <h3 class="special">SPECIAL EDITION</h3><h3>Flavour</h3><p>Dummy Text</p>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                          </div>
                     </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item" data-slide-number="10">
                     <div class="item-inner">
                          <div class="carousel-caption" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
                               <div class="hot-choc-info">
                                    <div class="hot-choc-info-inner">
                                    <h3 class="special">SPECIAL EDITION</h3><h3>Flavour</h3><p>Dummy Text</p>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                          </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="item" data-slide-number="11">
                     <div class="item-inner">
                          <div class="carousel-caption" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
                               <div class="hot-choc-info">
                                    <div class="hot-choc-info-inner">
                                    <h3>Flavour</h3><p>Dummy Text</p>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                          </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="item vip" data-slide-number="12">
                     <div class="item-inner">
                          <div class="carousel-caption" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
                               <div class="hot-choc-info">
                                    <div class="hot-choc-info-inner">
                                    <h3>Flavour</h3><p>Dummy Text</p>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                          </div>
                     </div>
                </div>

              </div>


                  <div class="row SA-slider-thumbs" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Bottom switcher of slider -->
      <ul class="hide-bullets">

        <li class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
          <a data-target="SA-slider-thumbs" class="thumbnail active SA-slider-thumb" id="carousel-selector-9"><img src="https://i1.wp.com/www.charitycomms.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/placeholder-image-square.jpg?ssl=1">Flavour</a>
        </li>

        <li class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
          <a data-target="SA-slider-thumbs" class="thumbnail SA-slider-thumb" id="carousel-selector-10"><img src="https://i1.wp.com/www.charitycomms.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/placeholder-image-square.jpg?ssl=1">Flavour</a>
        </li>

        <li class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
          <a data-target="SA-slider-thumbs" class="thumbnail SA-slider-thumb" id="carousel-selector-11"><img src="https://i1.wp.com/www.charitycomms.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/placeholder-image-square.jpg?ssl=1">Flavour</a>
        </li>

        <li class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
          <a data-target="SA-slider-thumbs" class="thumbnail SA-slider-thumb" id="carousel-selector-12"><img src="https://i1.wp.com/www.charitycomms.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/placeholder-image-square.jpg?ssl=1">Flavour</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
            
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/Slider-->

</div>

<!-- Third Tab -->
          <div id="pack3" class="tabcontent">
                 <p style="margin: 0 12px 24px 12px;">Dummy Text</p>
                
          </div>
          </div>
     </div>
     </div>

<!-- End of Hot Chococlate tabs -->
</div>
```